# Using Sharepoint webservices to get the ID/GUID of a custom field

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webservices-client

I am trying to get the ID/GUID of a custom column field from one of my Document libraries using web services.  How does one go about doing this in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the GUID via the SiteData webservice, the Webs webserivce doesn't retrive the ID....

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/3dd5871c-b52e-45c9-8ab2-9b9be092dede/

Comment: an alternative to this is also to get the "WebId" attribute from one of the <List> nodes returned by Lists.getLists()

Answer (score 0):

Ola!

Try this in C#

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web as SPWeb;
Guid id = web.AvailableContentTypes["ContentTypeName"].Fields["FieldName"].Id;
```

Regards,

Pedro